# Update file paths to movies in PowerPoint

Tags: video, path, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I have recently had my work laptop upgraded to Windows 7 (from XP). This, of course, led to changes in the paths to "My Documents" (now `C:\Users\...`, formerly `C:\Documents and Settings\...`).

One consequence of this is that now PowerPoint 2007 won't play video files in my presentation as it stored the absolute path to them (I keep them in the `My Videos` folder). I have read in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/42661/how-to-embed-video-in-powerpoint-with-relative-paths) that PowerPoint doesn't support relative paths.

What I'd like to know: Is there a way to correct the wrong paths in my presentations, short of removing each video and re-embedding it? When I double-click a video, all that PowerPoint does is tell me it can't find it - but it doesn't give me a chance to change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPoint does support relative paths.  Sort of.

If you insert the video/audio file from the same folder that the PPT itself is saved in, you get a relative path.

You could give this a try (on a COPY of your PPT files, please):

Batch Search and Replace for Hyperlinks, OLE links, movie links and sound links
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00773.htm

It'd let you modify the old path to the new path on every link in a presentation.

Comment: It appears that many of your answers serve to promote a product you are affiliated with. Please read the self-promotion portion of the [FAQ#promotion]: you are _required_ to disclose your affiliation with any products you recommend in your answers. Spamming can result in those answers being deleted and your account being suspended.

Comment: Additionally, your answer would be much more useful if you included the VB code and explained how to use it in addition to providing the reference. Just providing an external link is not as useful.

Comment: If you followed the link, you'd see that the page simply provides some code that might solve OP's problem.  At the bottom of that page, there's a link to another page that explains in detail how to use VBA code in PowerPoint.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I did follow the link, but the info on how to use it was not obvious. The way Super User works is that you are expected to provide a complete enough answer that it could stand on its own without the link, or at the very least the user could understand how it works without following the link. Furthermore, many of your posts have linked to the same site, as well as the link in your profile. This is a clear indication of self-promotion. We appreciate helpful answers, and it does look like many of your answers may be useful, but full disclosure of self-promotion is _mandatory_.

Comment: The site linked to is a large FAQ.  I'm not sure how that qualifies as self-promotion, in that there's no charge for using the thing, but if that's the way it is, that's the way it is.  If a link to a useful answer isn't acceptable, I won't bother.  Sorry to have been troublesome.  Over and out.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg because it doesn't cost money and you've provided some other very useful answers, your links are OK, all we ask is that you mention briefly that you are associated with the site, and include the answer, in your answer. The expectation that you include details in your answer, not just a link, is the same site-wide, regardless of whether the user is affiliated with the link provided or not. Don't get me wrong - your contributions have been useful, but we need to make sure that affiliations are disclosed.