# Change movie path in Microsoft PowerPoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update file paths to movies in PowerPoint](https://superuser.com/questions/286285/update-file-paths-to-movies-in-powerpoint)

I've created a PowerPoint presentation in my Windows 7 PC. I used a lot of avi video but when I added my PowerPoint presentation in my laptop (Windows XP) the videos are not working, it shows a black screen. All codecs are installed and also the video are working ok in media player. There is not a path issue because video are in same folder as the presentation.

My solution is to change .avi to .mpg (stupid solution but works) but I need to change the path of the video. A solution to delete the video and add it again its not good for me because for every video I have custom animations and custom thumbnails.

So maybe something to edit the link and change .avi to .mpg.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

Batch Search and Replace for Hyperlinks, OLE links, movie links and sound links
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00773.htm

It's a bit of VBA code that'll let you search/replace on all the link paths in your presentation.