# How do I link to excel chart data in PowerPoint with relative paths?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-powerpoint, charts, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

This question is similar to the question posted in

[How do I embed video in PowerPoint with relative paths?](https://superuser.com/questions/42661/how-do-i-embed-video-in-powerpoint-with-relative-paths/229258#229258?newreg=3ef09188ca3248d08f3fe6818e85e005)

But in my case I search for an answer to get Excel charts, which are linked in an absolute way, now linked in a relative way.

I especially liked the answer https://superuser.com/a/229258/301057 , but unfortunately, I did not get it working in any way to link to Excel files in a relative way. (I am using Office 2010)

The question remains: did I use the wrong relative path syntax, or is this something truly not possible in PowerPoint? Powerpoint just keeps telling me it cannot find the document when trying to update its links. However, it does show the exact same path as a typed-in manually, in the data connections screen.

Can anyone please test this or advise me in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Links to images, sounds, movies and files like PDFs etc can be relative, though it takes a bit of trickery to force them to be.

Links to Excel and other such OLE objects cannot be relative.  They require a full path.

So the next question is:  why do you need the links to be relative?  Perhaps there's another solution to the problem.

Comment: Downvoted because ... ?  IMO, it's a legit answer. Paths to linked OLE objects *cannot* be relative.

Comment: Not mine, but perhaps because you are asking a question.  That should have been done in the comments before you answered.